# Geofence GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELLING error

Tags: android

What does Non-negative loitering delay needs to be set when transition types include GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELLING means? I got this error when I tried to run the sample GeofenceDetection provided by the android's website, and set the transition to DWELL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is gone after I add the `setLoiteringDelay(int loiteringDelayMs)` on my`Geofence.Builder` according the the [doc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.Builder.html#setLoiteringDelay(int)).